# Change the size of background video when browser size changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

when resizing my website vertically  it resizes as i want it to but when resizing horizontally
it doesn't fill the screen. The site is called www.dinomoz.com and here is the code i use for the background video.

Comment: Your code is missing... please add it.

Answer (score 0):

When the window resizes, you need to see if it needs to fill the space horizontally (and crop vertically) or vice versa. The following jQuery will do that:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($('body').width() < $('body').height()) {
        $('video').css({height:'100%',width:'auto'});
    } else {
        $('video').css({width:'100%',height:'auto'});
    }
});
```

Comment: hello thanks for your reply, is there a way to do it with css?.<div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left:0; right:0; width: auto%; height: auto%; z-index: -1;">
<video src="video/Rain.mp4"  width="100%" height="100%"  autoplay loop>
</video>
</div>

Comment: Unfortunately, the CSS needs to change based on the shape of the screen. That's the JavaScript is small, because it's a simple fix, but you *do* need some JavaScript nonetheless

Comment: ok thanks for your reply bryce its much appreciated. I've included jQuery on my page do i just paste the code in that you've provided ?

Comment: Yes, after your jQuery script, preferably in a `$(document).ready()` block.